# SQL Column of type Date comes with Time

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Hi I have an App which works with a DB. And I have one table where one of the columns is of type Date, and in the DB it's fine. If I do a query to the table in question, the table will show only the Dates without time in that Column.

But something goes wrong when I get this table into my App and put it in a DataTable. When I do this Column of type Date will have the Date but with the Time and in all Dates appear for example like this (24-04-2011 00:00:00). How is this possible if the Column type in the DB is Date?

I am working with MS SQL Server in the server side, and with C# in App side.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to format your column's value .. The way differs depending on which control you are using ..

`DataGridView` has a collection of `DataGridViewColumn`. The `DataGirdViewColumn` has a property of the type `DataGridViewCellStyle` that has itself a `string` property called `Format`. You have to assign a value to the `Format` property to format the value showed in your column. In your case the appropriate value to assign is **"d"**.

You can assign a value for the mentioned property at design time or runtime.

---

Just for information:

**SQL Server** has a [Date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx) data type that takes only date values without time.

**C#** has a only a [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) data type wich consists of a date portion and a time portion as well. No data type for date or time seperately in **C#**. However, you can get the date portion or the time portion as strings using [DateTime.ToShortDateString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring.aspx) and [DateTime.ToShortTimeString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshorttimestring.aspx) respectively ..

Answer (score 2):

The datatype for dates in C# is DateTime, which invariably comes with a time. You can just ignore the time as it's insignificant (and always 00:00:00, for that matter).

Comment: But what i want is to hide the time when i am showing this column in a DataGrid for example. Doesn't make any sense the time being there...

Comment: @Miguel: Configure the view control to display only the date. I'm sure a datagrid supports at least something along the lines of a format string.

Comment: @Miguel: just define a proper format for your column! It's just a matter of displaying the data properly...

Answer (score 0):

While there is a `date` type in SQL Server, there is no such thing in .NET framework itsekf. Therefore, it uses whatever comes closer, which happens to be `DateTime`.

All in all, this is purely presentation issue: just format your output propery and you'll be fine.

Comment: SQL Server 2005 doesn't have a DATE type, only DATETIME. DATE was introduced with 2008.